# Button - Habilitado e desabilidado

Tags: react-native

Fiz um formulário com React Native, porém quero que o Button esteja desabilitado quando os TextInput estiverem vazios (não preenchidos), e quando tudo estiver preenchido, o Button volta a ficar habilitado.

Como eu posso fazer isso? Vocês podem me enviar exemplos de como eu faço isso?

**Obrigado**

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o teu código?

Answer (score 0):

Na propriedade disabled como você vai utilizar javascript puro, você pode fazer uma verificação booleana.
Está ai um exemplo de como utilizar.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    login:'',
    senha:''
  }

  render() {
    const { login, senha } = this.state;
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <TextInput placeholder='Login' 
          value={ login } 
          onChangeText={ text => this.setState({ login:text }) }
        />
        <TextInput placeholder='Senha' 
          value={ senha } 
          onChangeText={ text => this.setState({ senha: text }) } 
        />
        <Button 
        title='logar'
          onPress={() => { this.logar()}}
          disabled={ !(login.length && senha.length) }
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```